# mvc4 entity query how to improve this so that performance is better

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

The following code that I will show works correctly but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of getting this done that can improve performance. The jest of this is that I got 2 tables profiles and followers. This code is supposed to modify 2 records in the profiles table and add a record in the followers table.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public void AddFollower(int id,following followers)
    {
        // me wants to follows followee
        int me = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            followers.me = me;
            followers.ProfileID = id;
// Add new record on followers table
            db.followings.Add(followers);
            db.SaveChanges();
// Add +1 following for this persons profile & save it
            var UserA = (from s in db.profiles where s.ID == me select s).FirstOrDefault();
           UserA.following = UserA.following + 1;
            db.Entry(UserA).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
// Add +1 followers for this persons profile & save it
            var UserB = (from s in db.profiles where s.ID == id select s).FirstOrDefault();
            UserB.followers = profiles.followers + 1;
            db.Entry(UserB).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            scope.Complete();


        }



    }
```

The code above has a twitter like Functionality were if User A decides to follow User B then you most modify both their profiles in the database. This is done by increasing User A following count by 1 and increasing User B followers count by 1 and then offcourse creating that relationship in the followers table. This code works perfectly but I do not know if it could be written more efficient, I am essentially concerned that maybe this code might slow things down if there are a lot of users on the website.

Answer (score 0):

It's really redundant to store the numbers. That is a computed value, which can easily calculated with a simple count.

Comment: You mean deleting the followers,following numbers and whenever someone wants to see them just use a count query ?

Comment: Yes. I don't know how many request did you calculated, but I think not at that scale as twitter, so this will do it.